# How to fix Fortify Locale Dependent Comparison issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, fortify

In my springboot application when I can fortify to check vulnerabilities, I got some issues related to Locale Dependent Comparison .  I have number of files where fortify shows to fix Locale Dependent Comparison issue.
I have 3 options to change:

1. I have to go and change all those files by using Locale.US like below.

   from
    switch (strngvariable.toLowerCase())
   to 
    switch (strngvariable.toLowerCase(Locale.US))
2. During the spring Boot Initialization I can set the default locale as

   public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en","US"));
       SpringApplication.run(OWDNApplication.class, args);
     }
3. In the first REST call, set the default locale as

   @GetMapping("/applogin")
     public ResponseEntity getSignonDetails(@RequestParam("uname") String uname)
     {
       Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en","US"));

   }

   I know the first thing will work. I want to know will the 2 and 3 options work ? which would be the best choice.
   I can try on my own and figure it out if by running Fortify scan on my eclipse. Unfortunately the fortify plugin is not showing me all the issues on my local.
   I have to deploy onto server and run the software on server. this would be time consuming to test the changes.

Comment: Option 3 is bad. Setting a global option in a request-handling method is very troublesome. Do not use option 3.

Comment: Option 4: Specify the locale when starting the program, using `-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US`.

Comment: @Andrea, Thanks! What do you mean when starting the program? You mean spring Boot Initialization class?

Comment: In application.properties if we set ,                                                 spring.mvc.locale=en_US
spring.mvc.locale-resolver=fixed                                                                                              will it work?

Comment: starting the program = running the `java` command